# Array modifier displacement

Tags: modifiers, objects, dupli-groups

I'm working on som abstract art in blender, and therefore I want to use the array modifier. The problem is that I want to have some displacement on my object. See the picure below:

[image]

I want to edit every single hexagon object. This model is made with the Child-parent and a displace modifier on the object.

How can I make this, so that I can edit every hexagon, and not just the parent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1st make the duplicates real with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or object menu/apply/make duplicates real.
[image]
then make them single user with <kbd>U</kbd> (or object menu/make single user) objects & Data (& materials if needed)
[image]
Now you have different objects with different mesh data you can edit.